# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('.....how do I fix it?

Tags: bash, syntax-error, pycharm

```
echo 'alias charm="C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4/bin/pycharm.exe"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

This is my setup command for PyCharm using Bash. When I reopen the window and type

```
charm
```

I get the error mentioned.

Could someone help me with the error here?

Comment: That works fine in my Bash.  Are you sure you've given us all of the relevant facts?

Comment: You'll have to escape the spaces and the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the pathname, because of all the special characters it contains. Since you can't escape single quotes inside single quotes, you need to use double quotes as the outer delimiter, and then escape the inner double quotes.

```
echo "alias charm=\"'C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4/bin/pycharm.exe'\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

It would probably be easier if you just edited `.bashrc` by hand, and added the line:

```
alias charm="'C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4/bin/pycharm.exe'"
```

to it.

Comment: The first part of your solution worked! Thanks a ton